# Is there any efficient algorithm for computing all semigroups of order n?

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Is there any efficient algorithm for computing all semigroups of order n?

I found the following paper which solves a bit different problem.

- Veronique Froidure and Jean-Eric Pin, "[Algorithms for computing finite semigroups](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/Rio.pdf)"

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? There are exponentially many semigroups, so you cannot do better than exponential time.

Comment: I thought like this: So we have n^n^2 binary algebraic structurs of order n, (if consider they're all specified by Cayley's tables A[1],A[2],...A[n^n^2]) is it possible to fix a table A[i] which is a semigroup, can we say for some A[j]...A[k] tables they're semigroups too?

Comment: J.E. Pin, one of the authors of the paper, comments here frequently. Maybe you can contact him directly. Please share the answer here.

Comment: Regarding finding other semigroups $A[j]$ from a given $A[i]$, any permutation on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ will give you an isomorphic semigroup. (Or would you consider these the same?)

Comment: @KlausDraeger You are wrong, If **A[i]** is a semigroup it doesn't mean that any  permutation on {1,…,n} will give us an isomorphic semigroup.

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan if $*$ is the operation represented by $A[i]$ and $\pi$ is a permutation, then $\circ$ given by $x\circ y=\pi^{-1}(\pi(x)*\pi(y))$ should again be a semigroup operation. Sorry for leaving out those details.

Answer (score 3):

You asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1756306/80190)
and I answered it. Jean-Eric's algorithm is for computing the elements (among other things) of a semigroup defined by a generating set, and is not related to your question.

Comment: I know it, there I comented on your answer.

Comment: Crossposting the same question on different stackexchange sites is against our site policy.